# Exclude the overlay app icon from a screenshot

Tags: android, overlay, screenshot

Im just brainstorming an idea and Im checking its possibility before starting the code.
Lets say I have an app that takes a screenshot whenever I tap on its overlayed icon on screen,is there a way to exclude my app's icon from the resulting image?

Comment: Hide the icon. Take the screenshot. Restore the icon.

Comment: @CommonsWare Lol this solves my example, but it doesn't work on my original idea, any other way without hiding it? I don't wanna change anything on the screen, but only on the resulting image.

Comment: Um, well, if you know where your icon is, you can always modify the resulting image at that location to do... something. I have no idea what you would replace your icon with, though. The media projection APIs do not have support for "take a screenshot, but ignore this window, and so take the screenshot as if the stuff underneath the window were showing", if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately that's what im asking. so its not possible, thank you for the help

Comment: @CommonsWare, How *AirDroid Business* is able to [**it**](https://img-1-cdn.airdroid.com/assets/img/business/product/gif_remote_black_screen-24a88254e4.gif)? see [**Black Screen Mode**](https://blog.airdroid.com/post/protect-corporate-privacy-with-black-screen-mode).

Comment: @Coringa: Presumably, they are not using the media projection APIs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The media projection APIs simply capture what is on the screen. There is no means to say "ignore this window", other than by making the window not be there (or be transparent) at the time of the screen capture.

Answer (score 0):

very simple

hide the icon at the capture time and then make it visible after that.